# "Failed to call HTTP server" error after upgrading SonarQube from 6.0 to 6.7.2

Tags: sonarqube, upgrade, http-status-code-503

I have upgraded a SonarQube server from 6.0 to 6.7.2. Everything is fine, except that, after logging in as user "admin" and navigating to tab `Administration`, clicking on subtab `System` yields an error message 
`An error has occurred: please contact your administrator`.

In file web.log:

```
    2018.03.06 11:38:24 ERROR web[AWH6436/ICo3FeIjAAAz][o.s.s.w.WebServiceEngine] Fail to process request http://<HOST NAME>:20295/sonarqube/api/system/info

    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to call HTTP server of process [key='ce', ipcIndex=3, logFilenamePrefix=ce]

    at org.sonar.ce.http.CeHttpClientImpl.call(CeHttpClientImpl.java:171)
    at org.sonar.ce.http.CeHttpClientImpl.retrieveSystemInfo(CeHttpClientImpl.java:60)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.ws.StandaloneSystemInfoWriter.write(StandaloneSystemInfoWriter.java:53)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.ws.InfoAction.handle(InfoAction.java:64)
    at org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceEngine.execute(WebServiceEngine.java:103)
    at org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceFilter.doFilter(WebServiceFilter.java:86)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter$GodFilterChain.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:126)
    ...
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://10.145.61.55
```

The IP address is that of the server. There is no mention of any port in the error message, I don't know if this has any relation with the error.

It seems that the Web component cannot access the Compute Engine component. However nothing particular was found in file `ce.log` which ends with a trace `Compute Engine is operational`.

I followed the short migration guide in https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading.

Environment: Linux, JDK 8, Oracle DB

Does anyone as a clue? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For whoever who might stumble on the same issue: it was an error in my proxy configuration. Increasing the logging level by setting `sonar.log.level=DEBUG` in file `sonar.properties` yielded the following new traces in file `web.log`:

```
    2018.03.07 11:52:04 DEBUG web[AWIAFTpArQRjrTzMAAAg][s.n.w.p.h.HttpURLConnection] sun.net.www.MessageHeader@668ee27b5 pairs: {GET http://127.0.0.1:40413/systemInfo HTTP/1.1: null}{User-Agent: SonarQube 6.7.2.37468 # AWHmcYEU8aGLjZ5sPfjj Java/1.8.0_60}{Host: 127.0.0.1:40413}{Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2}{Proxy-Connection: keep-alive}
    2018.03.07 11:52:04 DEBUG web[AWIAFTpArQRjrTzMAAAg][s.n.w.p.h.HttpURLConnection] sun.net.www.MessageHeader@527214044 pairs: {null: HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently}{Server: BlueCoat-Security-Appliance}{Location: http://10.145.61.55}{Connection: Close}
    2018.03.07 11:52:04 DEBUG web[AWIAFTpArQRjrTzMAAAg][s.n.w.p.h.HttpURLConnection] Redirected from http://127.0.0.1:40413/systemInfo to http://10.145.61.55
    2018.03.07 11:52:04 ERROR web[AWIAFTpArQRjrTzMAAAg][o.s.s.w.WebServiceEngine] Fail to process request http://<HOST NAME>:20295/sonarqube/api/system/info
```

The proxy was redirecting the Compute engine URL `http://127.0.0.1:40413/systemInfo` to `http://10.145.61.55`.

The solution was to add `127.0.0.1` to `http.nonProxyHosts` in file `sonar.properties`.